# Even though SELinux, firewalld, iptables are disabled on my VPS "curl: (7) Failed connect to ... Connection refused error"

Tags: centos7, vps, connection

I rented a KWM VPS storage server (CentOS 7) and I can access it via SSH and SFTP.

But I can't do anything with it because it refuses everything. I didn't install anything on it, didn't change any config, havent done anything. Fresh OS install.
(except for deactivating firewall and selinux which were automatically on)

curl

```
# curl xx.xx.xxx.xxx
curl: (7) Failed connect to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80; Connection refused
```

netstat

```
# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1226/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1148/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1226/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1148/master
```

SELinux

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.
```

Firewalld

```
systemctl status firewalld
â— firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

iptables

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I don't know what else to check on?

VPS support says they didn't block any port and that it is a problem from "inside the KWM".

From literally 3 days of googling, the only other 2 options might be maybe that my IP runs twice and maybe it is a NAS server? But I wouldn't know how to check on these things and it is just a guess. Or maybe some SSL stuff? Or vhost things? I don't know. I have not much clue about servers, so please help me, if you have the time. Much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do you believe that curl should be able to connect to that IP address?

Comment: Good question. Shouldn't one be able to curl its own IP from inside the server? I try to run a min.io server (S3 compatible service) on it on port 9000. It runs (browser access) but I can't connect to that min.io service from another server because connection is refused no matter what. Before you ask "but perhaps port 9000 was not open", it was and all things were disabled. It lets me to believe in general any kind of connection to this server is refused, no matter what I do. So maybe you guys have any idea how to find out if it is true or not. @MichaelHampton

Comment: You didn't try to connect to port 9000!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know. Because this is a fresh install and there is nothing running on port 9000. First I want to be sure that in general the server can be connected to. I want to rule out if everything is okay with the server. Would you know how I can make sure one can connect to the server? Not port 9000, I mean in general. Curl refuses as you see and typing the IP on my browser gives timeout error or connection refused error.

Comment: You can't connect to a service that isn't running! Checking the firewall or SELinux is pointless because no service is listening.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Interesting. As I said, I am not a server guy. So does this mean curling own IP on the same server will return connection refused, too?

Comment: As `netstat` tells you, there are only sshd (port 22) and a local postfix (SMTP, "master", port 25) accepting TCP connections on that VPS. If you install and configure further services they will be reachable on their respective ports.